# New versions of Python hangs on imaplib.IMAP4_SSL()

Tags: python, ssl, imap

I have application that import emails from client IMAP4 mailboxes on `home.pl` (I think it is popular provider in Poland). It worked very well up to Python 2.7.9 but with version 2.7.10 it hangs on read() in `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL()`.

On my Fedora 23 I have Python 3.4.3 and 2.7.10.

With Python 3.4.3 such code works as expected:

```
[mn] python3 -c "import imaplib; x=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.home.pl', 993); print('finish', x)"
finish <imaplib.IMAP4_SSL object at 0x7f80cfd31710>
```

But with Python 2.7.10 it hangs. I pressed Ctrl-C after few seconds:

```
[mn] python -c "import imaplib; x=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.home.pl', 993); print('finish', x)"
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1166, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    typ, dat = self.capability()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 374, in capability
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1088, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 910, in _command_complete
    typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1017, in _get_tagged_response
    self._get_response()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 929, in _get_response
    resp = self._get_line()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1027, in _get_line
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1189, in readline
    return self.file.readline()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 451, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 734, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 621, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

You can also test it with docker to see that it worked with older versions of Python:

```
[mn] sudo docker run --rm -it python:2.7.9 python -c "import imaplib; x=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.home.pl', 993); print('finish', x)"
('finish', <imaplib.IMAP4_SSL instance at 0x7f682422b2d8>)

[mn] sudo docker run --rm -it python:2.7.10 python -c "import imaplib; x=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.home.pl', 993); print('finish', x)"
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1166, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    typ, dat = self.capability()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 374, in capability
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1088, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 910, in _command_complete
    typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1017, in _get_tagged_response
    self._get_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 929, in _get_response
    resp = self._get_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1027, in _get_line
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1189, in readline
    return self.file.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 451, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 734, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 621, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The same way I tested that it hangs with Python 3.4.4.

I think it is a bug because it hangs instead of raising an exception with helpful information so I reported it: http://bugs.python.org/issue26375

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Does it hang forever?  Did you let it sit for a minute?

Comment: There is a problem with the server, it hangs on a CAPABILITY request, which is very very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a server issue, it is not responding to the CAPABILITY command (< and > added for clarity):

```
$ socat readline openssl:imap.home.pl:993,crlf,verify=0 
< * OK imap.home.pl IdeaImapServer v0.80 ready
> tag CAPABILITY
```

And it sits there for a very long time.  There may be an issue with the server.

Strangely, sending two commands back to back kicks it:

```
< a CAPABILITY
< b CAPABILITY
> * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ CHILDREN I18NLEVEL=1 IDLE SORT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN XLIST AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN
> a OK Completed
> * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ CHILDREN I18NLEVEL=1 IDLE SORT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN XLIST AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN
> b OK Completed
```

There is a serious parsing bug in the server.

Comment: It is possible older versions of imaplib don't issue a CAPABILITY command right away; and newer versions do.  Either way, it is an extremely critical part of the IMAP protocol.  You won't get far without it.

Comment: I don't have a login for this server, so I can't test if this "fixes" itself after login.